# How to create rolling average data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sas, moving-average

I have a table like this:

```
Week prod Value
1    A     2.3
1    B     4.1
1    C     6.3
2    A     0
2    B     3.4
2    C     1.4
3    A     4.2
3    B     2.5
3    C     6.7
```

Now i have similar data for lot of weeks and I want to roll up say 3 weeks 1,2,3 and make it week 1, and take average value for prods(A,B,C), like this next roll up 2,3,4 and make it week 2 and take average value for prods and keep doing till last week.

Comment: Mean, mode or median - which one?

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: @ed: arithmetic mean

Comment: @zara: My sql server

Comment: Do you mean "MySQL" server or my "SQL Server"? Those are two different things

Answer (score 1):

Many databases support the ANSI standard window functions:

```
with weeks as (
      select week, sum(value) as value
      from table t
      group by week
     )
select week, value,
       avg(value) over (order by week range between 2 preceding and current row) as avg_3week
from weeks;
```

EDIT:

You can write this with a subquery instead:

```
select week, value,
       avg(value) over (order by week range between 2 preceding and current row) as avg_3week
from (select week, sum(value) as value
      from table t
      group by week
     ) weeks;
```

You may need to make this a pass-through query in SAS.  `proc sql` doesn't do window functions.

Comment: how to write with weeks in sql environment, my sql starts only from select

Comment: @user2542275 . . . SQL Server supports CTEs and since 2012 supports windowing clauses as well.  So this should work.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  SQL Server has supported them since SQL Server 2005.

Comment: its sql server 2008, but i am writing queries in SAS

Comment: @user2542275 . . . It should work if you use pass-through queries.  See:  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/63647/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000460370.htm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select id, avg(avg(val)) over(order by id ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING)
  from t
 group by id
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/21752)

If rolling windows aren't supported, you can use:

```
with tt(id, aval) as (
  select id, avg(val)
    from t
   group by id
)
select id, (select avg(aval) from tt tt1 where tt1.id between tt2.id and tt2.id + 2)
  from tt tt2
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/39500)

Without CTE:

```
select distinct id, (select avg(aval) 
              from (select id, avg(val) aval
                      from t
                     group by id
                   ) tt1 
             where tt1.id between tt2.id and tt2.id + 2)
  from t tt2
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/39506)

Comment: What version do you use? sql server 2008? sql server 2008r2? sql server 2012? sql server 2014? Do you know that even there is ANSI standard all databases have their own SQL dialect?

Comment: its sql server 2008, but i am writing queries in SAS

Comment: with function is not available in SAS

Comment: Do you have the SAS ETS license? If so look into proc expand.